# How to dynamically create and delete topic(s) using spring-kafka library

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

How to dynamically create and delete `Topics` using `spring-kafka` library ? Thanks.

What i have tried is `AdminClient`. But i need to have somekind of wrapper which can help me achieve this by using `spring-kafka` without creating custom class and testing it.

`spring-kafka` already have one to create a `Topic`. But for deletetion i have no idea.

Comment: Spring allows `@Bean Topic`. But for delete, you will need to "wrap" AdminClient. Maybe if you added your code, we can provide more input

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `AdminClient` for such operations.

https://kafka.apache.org/27/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html

Comment: Already have used it Gary. But i could not find any except `TopicBuilder` in `spring-kafka` to only create the topics.  I need something from `spring-kafka` library. if it is not available can i create a wrapper somehow ? Thanks.

Comment: @nihar Please edit your question to show what you've tried

Comment: `spring-kafka` provides `KafkaAdmin` which only supports a small subset of the `AdminClient` functionality - it is used to create topics for `@Bean`s of type `NewTopic` during application startup. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#configuring-topics For all other operations (e.g. dynamic add/remove topics at runtime) you must use the `AdminClient` directly.

Comment: Thanks Gary. But according to  https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/api/org/springframework/kafka/core/KafkaAdmin.html#initialize(). -> You can create topics without a broker after the application context is initialized. But what is the need of topic then if the broker does not exist ?

Comment: If there are `NewTopic` beans (and a `KafkaAdmin`) the framework will try to check for or create the topics during initialization. By default, the application won't start if the broker is down. If you set that boolean to false, the application will start and you can manually call `initialize()` to create the topics defined by the beans. You can also add beans to the application context later and calling `initializ()` will create them.